# How do I solve this error in dropwizard config file?

Tags: java, hibernate, yaml, dropwizard

I am getting the following error when I run my jar while using:

```
java -jar <jarPath>.jar server config.yml
```

Error:

```
  * Configuration at config.yml must not be empty

        at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:279)
        at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:85)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:79)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
        at com.flipkart.cx.taggingconsole.webapp.application.DataConsoleApp.main(DataConsoleApp.java:62)
```

Ans here is my config file, I am quite new to all this and trying to connect my dropwizard application to hibernate using config.yml and not hibernate.cfg.xml.

Please have a look at config.yml file

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    -   type: http
        port: 8800
  adminConnectors:
    -   type: http
        port: 9800
# Database settings.
database:

  # the name of your JDBC driver
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  # the username
  user: root

  # the password
  password: root1234

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:h2:./target/example
  properties:
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate.connection.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    hibernate.connection.driver_class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    hibernate.show_sql: false
    hibernate.generate_statistics: false
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update # validates schema when service is started
    hibernate.current_session_context_class: thread
```

Comment: It seems that you have some error in yaml file and from that it cannot be parsed.
Try to remove `database` section and check if it go further (it will fall down on other error), but by adding/removing other parts of yaml you will find out where is the problem

Comment: Still getting the same error? Any other way to resolve it?

Comment: Mayby you realy have an empty file `config.yml`? Try to copy it to other file (`config2.yml`) and use it in run command. Maybe you point to wrong location?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the snippets of your configuration as well?

Comment: I have the same error even with minimal yaml file (only http app connector, port 8080). @AdityaVerma, if you succeeded to fix your issue, please post an answer

Answer (score 0):

On my case I had dropwizard's app jar produced by fatjar plugin and thus it couldn't see the file outside of jar. When I put my `config.yml` to the resources directory in project and compiled app again, it could find the file.